# In Sql Server 2008 Order by clause is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have run a query

```
SELECT Datename(MM, CONVERT(DATE, created_date))           AS open_date, 
       Count(Datename(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, created_date))) AS created_request 
FROM   usm_request 
WHERE  Datename(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, created_date)) = Datename(YEAR, Getdate()) 
GROUP  BY Datename(MM, CONVERT(DATE, created_date)) 
ORDER  BY Datename(MM, CONVERT(DATE, created_date)) ASC
```

and got the result

```
 open_date  created_request

   April          4
   February      194
   January       540
   March         186
```

But we need result as

```
  open_date  created_request

   January       540
   February      194
   March         186    
   April          4
```

Please help me.

Regards

Pankaj

Comment: `DATENAME` returns a string not a datetime, so you get a lexicographic ordering.

Comment: I don't have this much of experience in database can you please help me to write lexicographic ordering.

Answer (score 2):

`DATENAME` returns a string not a datetime, so you get a lexicographic ordering.

You could use:

```
SELECT Datename(MM, CONVERT(DATE, created_date))           AS open_date, 
       Count(Datename(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, created_date))) AS created_request 
FROM   usm_request 
WHERE  Datename(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, created_date)) = Datename(YEAR, Getdate()) 
GROUP  BY  DATENAME(mm,created_date),
       DATEPART(yy, created_date), 
       DATEPART(mm, created_date)
ORDER  BY DATEPART(yy, created_date),
          DATEPART(mm, created_date)
```

... which orders by year + month (as `int`). You also have to include them in the `GROUP BY`.

However, why do you convert the `datetime` column always to `Date`? That seems to be redundant with methods like `DATENAME`. So i've omitted it in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ORDER BY clause is receiving a string: the name of the month. This is why the rows are ordered alphabetically.

Try ordering by the actual date representation:

`ORDER  BY CONVERT(DATE, created_date) ASC`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT Datename(MM, CONVERT(DATE, created_date))           AS open_date, 
       Count(Datename(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, created_date))) AS created_request 
FROM   usm_request 
WHERE  Datename(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, created_date)) = Datename(YEAR, Getdate()) 
GROUP  BY Datename(MM, CONVERT(DATE, created_date)) 
) a
ORDER  BY a.created_request desc
```

Comment: If you think about it, this probably isn't what he wants. He wants it ordered by month.

Comment: from his expected output we can sat that "created_request" should be of descending order